# Apple recognized repair service asking for password?

Tags: macbook-pro, repair, applecare

I took my MacBook Pro to an Apple recognized provider for repair, and as part of the repair setup they asked for my account password... Is that a regular routine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty common for a repair facility of any kind to ask for a username/password for the sake of verifying functionality. This is why it's always a good idea to have a separate administrator account setup for these kind of tasks. Usually an "Administrator" account with a unique password works.

I've worked in the IT industry for almost 20 years, and I've always appreciated when a user has a separate admin account. It makes working on the machine faster as there usually isn't as much stuff loading on start up. It also keeps me from seeing any of your information, which is great for legal reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what they need to do. If it's purely hardware they can boot it from an external or use the guest account (assuming you set it up properly).

If it's a hardware / software combination they may need to install something in your system, and that requires an admin password.

Comment: I'm having  a graphics issue recognized by Apple last February (see [here](https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/)). They told me they will have to replace the whole logic board... I guess that means nothing to worry about?

Comment: That's hardware. They will want to check that it works correctly but they don't need your account to do it. However, the vast majority of users only have one account, so it's a standard question. based on your other comments you did not add another account in advance, so you either tell them your password or accept the repair unverified.